# How do I get a list of files in a directory in C++?

Tags: c++, file, directory

How do you get a list of files within a directory so each can be processed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

But `boost::filesystem` can do that: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp

Answer (score 61):

Here's what I use:

```
/* Returns a list of files in a directory (except the ones that begin with a dot) */

void GetFilesInDirectory(std::vector<string> &out, const string &directory)
{
#ifdef WINDOWS
    HANDLE dir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file_data;

    if ((dir = FindFirstFile((directory + "/*").c_str(), &file_data)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return; /* No files found */

    do {
        const string file_name = file_data.cFileName;
        const string full_file_name = directory + "/" + file_name;
        const bool is_directory = (file_data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0;

        if (file_name[0] == '.')
            continue;

        if (is_directory)
            continue;

        out.push_back(full_file_name);
    } while (FindNextFile(dir, &file_data));

    FindClose(dir);
#else
    DIR *dir;
    class dirent *ent;
    class stat st;

    dir = opendir(directory);
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        const string file_name = ent->d_name;
        const string full_file_name = directory + "/" + file_name;

        if (file_name[0] == '.')
            continue;

        if (stat(full_file_name.c_str(), &st) == -1)
            continue;

        const bool is_directory = (st.st_mode & S_IFDIR) != 0;

        if (is_directory)
            continue;

        out.push_back(full_file_name);
    }
    closedir(dir);
#endif
} // GetFilesInDirectory
```

Comment: The Windows code doesn't quite work when compiled with Unicode enabled. I got around this by explicitly calling the ASCII functions, which have an 'A' appended. Specifically, use WIN32_FIND_DATAA, FindFirstFileA, and FindNextFileA and everything works. Obviously this is a hack, but I live in an English speaking country so it works for me. :0 Thanks for the example code!

Comment: Can't use dirent if you are making a lib.

Comment: @tuple_cat `<dirent.h>`, `<sys/stat.h>` and for sure some kind of file that includes `std::string`. Using `std::string`, you have to put `std::` in front of the `string` type declaration and use `opendir(directory.c_str())`.

Answer (score 29):

Here's an example in C on Linux.  That's if, you're on Linux and don't mind doing this small bit in ANSI C.

```
#include <dirent.h>

DIR *dpdf;
struct dirent *epdf;

dpdf = opendir("./");
if (dpdf != NULL){
   while (epdf = readdir(dpdf)){
      printf("Filename: %s",epdf->d_name);
      // std::cout << epdf->d_name << std::endl;
   }
}
closedir(dpdf);
```

Comment: don't forget to `closedir(dpdf)` afterwards

Comment: how can i get a file (FILE type) in this case? epdf is a "dirent *"

Comment: Can't use dirent if you are making a lib.

Comment: @Katianie Why not?

Comment: What do `dpdf` and `epdf` stand for?

Comment: I was working with PDFs at the time. Those names could be anything you like.

Answer (score 6):

C++11/Linux version:

```
#include <dirent.h>

if (auto dir = opendir("some_dir/")) {
    while (auto f = readdir(dir)) {
        if (!f->d_name || f->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue; // Skip everything that starts with a dot

        printf("File: %s\n", f->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use operating system calls (e.g. the Win32 API) or a wrapper around them. I tend to use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) as it is superior interface compared to the mess that is the Win32 API (as well as being cross platform).

If you are looking to use the Win32 API, Microsoft has a list [of functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363950%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540535%28VS.85%29.aspx) on msdn.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Windows & using MSVC, the MSDN library has [sample code that does this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200.aspx)

And here's the code from that link:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction);

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
   LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
   TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
   size_t length_of_arg;
   HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
   DWORD dwError=0;

   // If the directory is not specified as a command-line argument,
   // print usage.

   if(argc != 2)
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("\nUsage: %s <directory name>\n"), argv[0]);
      return (-1);
   }

   // Check that the input path plus 2 is not longer than MAX_PATH.

   StringCchLength(argv[1], MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg);

   if (length_of_arg > (MAX_PATH - 2))
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("\nDirectory path is too long.\n"));
      return (-1);
   }

   _tprintf(TEXT("\nTarget directory is %s\n\n"), argv[1]);

   // Prepare string for use with FindFile functions.  First, copy the
   // string to a buffer, then append '\*' to the directory name.

   StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);
   StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

   // Find the first file in the directory.

   hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

   if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
   {
      ErrorHandler(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
      return dwError;
   } 

   // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.

   do
   {
      if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
      {
         _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);
      }
      else
      {
         filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
         filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
         _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   %ld bytes\n"), ffd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
      }
   }
   while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

   dwError = GetLastError();
   if (dwError != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) 
   {
      ErrorHandler(TEXT("FindFirstFile"));
   }

   FindClose(hFind);
   return dwError;
}


void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31051317/4383472) and here's my solution based on answer received (using `boost::filesystem` library):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    path p("D:/AnyFolder");
    for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
    {
        if (!is_directory(i->path())) //we eliminate directories in a list
        {
            cout << i->path().filename().string() << endl;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

Output is like:

```
file1.txt
file2.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

Solving this will require a platform specific solution. Look for opendir() on unix/linux or FindFirstFile() on Windows. Or, there are many libraries that will handle the platform specific part for you.

Answer (score 1):

After combining a lot of snippets, I finally found a reuseable solution for Windows, that uses ATL Library, which comes with Visual Studio.

```
#include <atlstr.h>

void getFiles(CString directory) {
    HANDLE dir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file_data;
    CString  file_name, full_file_name;
    if ((dir = FindFirstFile((directory + "/*"), &file_data)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // Invalid directory
    }

    while (FindNextFile(dir, &file_data)) {
        file_name = file_data.cFileName;
        full_file_name = directory + file_name;
        if (strcmp(file_data.cFileName, ".") != 0 && strcmp(file_data.cFileName, "..") != 0)
        {
            std::string fileName = full_file_name.GetString();
            // Do stuff with fileName
        }
    }
}
```

To access the method, just call:

```
getFiles("i:\\Folder1");
```

Comment: Can you mention if this is for Windows or Linux or both?

Comment: @NadavB it uses atlstr.h library, which I believe is only for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
HANDLE WINAPI FindFirstFile(
  __in   LPCTSTR lpFileName,
  __out  LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData
);
```

Setup the attributes to only look for directories.

Answer (score 0):

Or you do this and then read out the test.txt:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {    
system("dir /b > test.txt");
}
```

The "/b" means just filenames are returned, no further info.

Comment: This looks really nice and easy, but I don't get how to use this. Could you explain what is `/b` and where will we give the directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for getting all files in a directory.A simple modification in the Andreas Bonini answer to remove the occurance of "." and ".."

```
CString dirpath="d:\\mydir"
DWORD errVal = ERROR_SUCCESS;
HANDLE dir;
WIN32_FIND_DATA file_data;
CString  file_name,full_file_name;
if ((dir = FindFirstFile((dirname+ "/*"), &file_data)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    errVal=ERROR_INVALID_ACCEL_HANDLE;
    return errVal;
}

while (FindNextFile(dir, &file_data)) {
    file_name = file_data.cFileName;
    full_file_name = dirname+ file_name;
    if (strcmp(file_data.cFileName, ".") != 0 && strcmp(file_data.cFileName, "..") != 0)
    {
        m_List.AddTail(full_file_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void getFilesList(String filePath,String extension, vector<string> & returnFileName)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileInfo;
    HANDLE hFind;   
    String  fullPath = filePath + extension;
    hFind = FindFirstFile(fullPath.c_str(), &fileInfo);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){return;} 
    else {
        return FileName.push_back(filePath+fileInfo.cFileName);
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fileInfo) != 0){
            return FileName.push_back(filePath+fileInfo.cFileName);}
        }
 }


 String optfileName ="";        
 String inputFolderPath =""; 
 String extension = "*.jpg*";
 getFilesList(inputFolderPath,extension,filesPaths);
 vector<string>::const_iterator it = filesPaths.begin();
 while( it != filesPaths.end())
 {
    frame = imread(*it);//read file names
            //doyourwork here ( frame );
    sprintf(buf, "%s/Out/%d.jpg", optfileName.c_str(),it->c_str());
    imwrite(buf,frame);   
    it++;
 }
```

Comment: you have 2 returns in method getFilesList, the code after the  return FileName.push_back(filePath+fileInfo.cFileName); is not reachable