# How to read the mp3 files in a given folder?

Tags: c++

how to read the mp3 files and display those file names using c++ can anyone provide me code for this in C++?

Comment: dirent.h: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/dirent.h.html

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306533/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-c

Comment: -1 for show me the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the boost filesystem library, it's a very powerful library that will meet your needs. The documentation should make it easy for you to write this tiny piece of code yourself: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

I just saw that you actually can copy and slightly modify this example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp

Answer (score 0):

for a portable implementation you can use boost filesystem library that let you to create an iterator over a directory. 
take a look at boost doc here 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

there are also non portable function that works only on windows or on unix, but they work in the same way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick answer (nearly complete) using [boost.filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), adapted from an example of [basic_directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_directory_iterator).

```
void iterate_over_mp3_files( const std::string & path_string )
{
  path dir_path(path_string);
  if ( exists( dir_path ) )
  {
    directory_iterator end_itr; // default construction yields past-the-end
    for ( directory_iterator itr( dir_path );
          itr != end_itr;
          ++itr )
    {
      if ( ### ) // test for ".mp3" suffix with itr->leaf()
      {
        path path_found = itr->path();
        // do what you want with it
      }
  }    
}
```