# Is there a way to check if a folder contains subfolders?

Tags: delphi, filesystems

I want to know if there is a way to check if a folder contains subfolders, but without using the `FindFirst/FindNext` to check every item, because it's slow when the folder contains many files and no subfolders.

Comment: You have to enumerate the contents until you find a subfolder

Comment: I'd believe that it's *slower*, but not that it's actually *slow*. That makes me suspect you're doing something wrong.

Comment: [`FindFirstFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `fSearchOp` parameter set to [`FindExSearchLimitToDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#FindExSearchLimitToDirectories) might be faster.

Comment: .. and [unreliable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248911/file-system-support-for-findfirstfileex-limit-to-directories).

Comment: Time this from a CMD prompt at the root of a drive: "dir `*.*` /s > dump.txt".  Doing the equivalent thing in Delphi code using FindFirst/FindNext takes a few percent longer, 11 secs for ~250,000 files here.

Comment: @MartynA It might be interesting to compare that with `dir /ad/s` to determine if the OS uses a more efficient way of identifying subfolders. Though the output should be redirected elsewhere to avoid contaminating the benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in general there is no way to ask a file system object if it contains any directories. I think you need to enumerate the object's children as you have described, for instance with calls to `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile` etc.

Comment: Why not give a try to the `FindFirstFileEx` function with `FindExSearchLimitToDirectories` flag ? If the file system won't support directory filtering (and the call returns a non-directory object data), you'll just loop with the `FindNextFile` until you find a directory object. My point is that you can increase the speed by the chance that the file system supports that filtering and you'll find a directory with a single call in such case.

Comment: The supported file systems are known ? Is there a list somewhere ? I didn't find anything on google...