# how to get file names vs directory names in c++ (using boost filesystem library)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-filesystem

When I use `boost::filesystem` to get a list of file names in a directory, I receive file names as well as directory names:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    path p("D:/AnyFolder");
    for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
    {
        cout << i->path().filename().string() << endl;
    }
}
```

Output is like:

```
file1.txt
file2.dat
Folder1 //which is a folder
```

Is there a quick way to distinguish between files and folders?
My OS is Windows 8.1, if it matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a list of files in a directory in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306533/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[is_directory()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#is_directory)

```
boost::filesystem::is_directory(i->path());
```

Answer (score 6):

Final code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    path p("D:/AnyFolder");
    for (auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++)
    {
        if (!is_directory(i->path())) //we eliminate directories in a list
        {
            cout << i->path().filename().string() << endl;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

Output is like:

```
file1.txt
file2.dat
```