# reading .txt file's 2nd line and write to another .txt file - C++

Tags: c++, string, function, getline

I have 79 `.txt` files like this:

```
iRun iDate showerEnergy thetaRad phiRad totalShowers totalParticles  e+ e- μ+ μ-
4001 121125 5e+07 1.61401 0.00118607 1 9929166 6909475 1271116 1399686 151330 148624
-1 4001 121125 5e+07 1.61401 0.00118607 2 9929167 6909475 1271116 1399686 151330 148624
```

it has just 3 lines, 1st the `iRun iDate` on this line and 2nd is starting with `4001` and 3rd starting with `-1`. And I just want to read these text files' 2nd lines. Also I want to  write all 79 text files' 2nd lines in a text file if I read them clearly.

Comment: Which language do you want to use? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am a newbie to this kind of reading/writing works. I want to use C++ language, want a simple thing just want to read all whole 2nd lines of all x79 files, if i be able to read/write one, i can make the others.

Comment: I'm sorry my answer was for C# not C++. I just deleted it.

Comment: Try to looks at [all these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=line+reading+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) for how to read files by lines in C++

Comment: `getline(fin, line); getline(fin, line); fout << line << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very trivial with `<fstream>`. A very basic program would look something like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("indata.txt"); // Open input file
    std::string lineData = "";

    getline(infile, lineData); // Get first line.
    getline(infile, lineData); // Get second line.

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("outdata.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    outfile << lineData << std::endl; // Append lineData to outfile. Creates the file if necessary.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This just worked thank you a lot. But i want to ask a simple question too. How can i add just numbers for them in to their first starting lines, i mean when i writing the first text i want to add 1, and 2 for 2nd etc.

Comment: And of course, i can not write more than 1 txt file's 2nd line in another text file. I really don't understand. How can i duplicate your method for more than 40 txt files ? All 2nd lines must go to 1 common text file. I can just add first, second not works.

Comment: You will need to use a `for` loop. I'll let you investigate how to do that. There are plenty of resources for understanding them.

Answer (score 0):

try writing something.

psuedo code looks like this

```
open outfile
for each text file
{
   open file
   skip line
   read line
   write line to out file
   close file
}
close output file
```

so the first thing you are going to have to do is work out how to enumerte the files. Two choices:

- pass them in on command line via args. On unix the shell will expand , say, in*.txt toa list of actual file names
- use some function to get a list of files. the c way [How do you get a directory listing in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-in-c) or the c++ way [How do I get a list of files in a directory in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306533/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-c)

the rest is simple c++ file io

If this is a practical problem (as opposed to a class assignment) I would used awk, perl, sed etc rather than write code